# Spring Security and web application authenticating against GitHub

Tags: spring, github, oauth, spring-security

We have a web application with UI and also a REST service that the UI uses.

Now, I have managed to set up Spring Security in some basic configuration that allows login with user name and password. We want to extend this to authenticate users using existing GitHub accounts. I understand that GitHub uses OAuth. What I do not understand is how could this all work with our server side.

As I understand it, it should somehow work this way: The web UI checks whether it can find some kind of user secret token (a cookie?) and uses that in its requests to the REST service. The REST service needs some way to verify that the given user secret token is valid, so it has to contact GitHub OAuth serivce and somehow verify it. Is this right? Or is the mechanism completely different?

If the above is right, do I need to remember the user secret token on the server side for some time or do I re-verify it for each request with GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Spring Social GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-github) from [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-github/)